# Can you side-load relations in a Django Rest Framework response?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an API endpoint that needs to return many thousands of results that share relations. I would like to return the ID on each result and then return a second set of data containing each of the relations (rather than repeating the relations on each result). What's the best way to go about side-loading relations?

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: Sure, but it's hard to keep concise. I have a model for `sighting` that has a many-to-many relationship to `species`. I can serialize each and return them with DRF, but the species data will be repeated across sightings, making the result huge. I'd like to side-load the species so they are only returned once.

Comment: What about a second endpoint? 
How should this sideloading look like? Simple another array at the end of your response that serializes all your `species` instances?

Comment: That's what I'm doing now.
It would be more efficient to sideload if it were possible. At the moment, I have to wait for the sighting response, find all the unique species, then request those species as a second call (I only want to load the relevant species for the current batch of sightings).

Comment: But the goal is to include all unique serialized `species` instances in the _same_ response, right?

Comment: Yes, but a subset of species. The response may only need 5/1000 species because those are the only ones referenced by the current sightings.